# glassfish server no me genera json

Tags: java, json, xml, glassfish

Tengo un servicio web en Netbeans que coje los datos de mysql que tengo en un servidor glassfish remoto. Cuando pruebo el servicio en local, me genera tanto los xml como los json. El problema lo tengo cuando subo el servicio al servidor que no me genera el json, los xml si.

El código del metodo get de una tabla de la base de datos es:

```
@GET
    @Override
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public List<Estats> findAll() {
        return super.findAll();
    }
```

En el Postman me sale el XML y si cambio a JSON me sale `Unexpected '<'`. Cuando abro la url en el navegador solo me muestra el xml.

He probado de quitar el `MediaType.APPLICATION_XML` para que no me muestre el xml y me sale el siguiente error:
[image: error del servidor Glassfish]

Es decir:

```
type Exception report

 messageInternal Server Error

 descriptionThe server encountered an internal error that prevented it
 from fulfilling this request.

 exception

 javax.servlet.ServletException:
 org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException:
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
 org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.BeanValidationHelper

 root cause

 org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException:
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
 org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.BeanValidationHelper

 root cause

 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
 org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.BeanValidationHelper

 note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are
 available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1.1 logs.
```

Como puedo solucionar esto? Muchas gracias.

Comment: Verificaste que la versión de tu glassfish local como de la BD sean las mismas que las del servidor?

Comment: Si, tanto en local como en remoto tengo el 4.1.1

Comment: Puedes revisar el log que se genera?, lo encuentras en la carpeta donde se instala el Glassfish, porque ahí dice que el error es en una de las persistencias que ocasiona la excepción en el glassfish, aunque para mi es la versión del glassfish, pero si dices que en tu local te funciona...

Comment: [2017-03-21T13:25:49.942+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.resourceadapter.mqjmsra.lifecycle] [tid: _ThreadID=340 _ThreadName=admin-listener(14)] [timeMillis: 1490099149942] [levelValue: 800] [[
  MQJMSRA_RA1101: GlassFish MQ JMS Resource Adapter Started:EMBEDDED]]

Comment: El mensaje suena a que el glassfish remoto no tiene instaladas las librerias JAXB... quizás las incluiste a mano en el servidor local y no te acuerdas?

Comment: @SJuan76 sabes que librerias son?

Comment: https://www.google.es/search?q=jaxb+jar; en todo caso la pregunta era por si te sonaba haberlas añadido tú a tu instalación en local; si estás segura de no haberlas añadido por tu cuenta entonces ya no digo nada.

Comment: Solucioné el error instalando un nuevo servidor glassfish de una versión inferior dentro de Netbeans

Comment: La solución COMPROBADA es hacer lo que esta en el comentario: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45762121

Comment: La solución COMPROBADA esta en: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45762121

Answer (score 0):

Que tal,

Al parecer es un bug de Glassfish 4.1.1, lo que yo realice es descargar la .jar  de org.eclipse.persistence.moxy-2.6.0.jar y lo sustituí por que esta en /$GLASSFISHINSTALL/glassfish/modules lo deje con el nombre de   org.eclipse.persistence.moxy.jar como estaba el otro

Comment: Hola @ArminMontana , Bienvenido a [StackOverflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com), te recomiendo un [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) por la pagina para poder ganar tu primera medalla, y ver [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) para hacer un [ejemplo minimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) y la comunidad acepte de buena forma tu pregunta